# Lazy evaluation when use lambda and list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-evaluation

Here is the example python code.

```
f_list = [lambda x : x ** i for i in range(5)]
[f_list[j](10) for j in range(5)]
```

I thought the output would be:

```
[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
```

But I got this instead:

```
[10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000]
```

I'm wondering what actually happened when I run this code. And what's the connections with lazy evaluation.

Comment: There's definite a duplicate for this somewhere. In short, your functions are not closures over `i`; each function in `f_list` is the *exact* same function whose body references a global variable `i`, whose value is looked up when the function is *called*.

Comment: The result is [10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000]

Comment: Yes, because each and every function in the list sees `i == 4` when it gets called, as that's the last value assigned to `i` by the list comprehension. The value of `i` at the time the `lambda` expression is evaluated to produce the function is irrelevant.

Comment: For Python 3 (to correct my original comment), `i` is not a global variable, but a non-local variable specific to the list comprehension but shared by all the functions

Comment: @AndyK I just forgot the “0”

Comment: @chepner Thx! Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: Personally, I prefer this `f_list = [lambda x, j=i : x ** j for i in range(5)]` and
`[f_list[j](10) for j in range(5)]` gives `[1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good example of why curryfying is good, you can achieve your goal currying your function like this:

```
f_list = [(lambda y : lambda x : x ** y)(i) for i in range(5)]
r = [f_list[j](10) for j in range(5)]
```

The result will be:

```
=> [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
```

**Currying:**

The simple way to understand what curry is for me is the next one, instead of give to a function all the parameters it needs, you create a function, that always receives one parameter, and returns another function that takes again one parameter, and in the final function, you do the transformation you need with all the parameters

A little example:

```
sum_curry = lambda x : lambda y : x + y
```

here you've got a simple sum function, but imagine you want to have the function plus_one, ok, yuu can reuse the function above like this:

```
plus_one = sum_curry(1)
```

Comment: You might mention what currying (not "curryfying") is, since it's not a common concept in Python. (And better yet, *why* it's necessary.)

Comment: @chepner I hope it's a little bit clear now

Comment: It really makes the code more pythonic. Thx!

Comment: @chaos_ko you are welcome! don't forget to always accept one answer, your favorite, with the ✓top left